# JAXB: Unmarshalling of different XML elements with same values

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

*There is a plethora of questions on roughly the same topic, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. My apologies if I missed it.*

I'm trying to unmarshal XML files that have common logical elements, but defined with different tags:

#### Xml input file

```
<xml>
  <animals>
    <dog>
      <bark>loud</bark>
    </dog>
    <cat>
      <meow>frail</meow>
    </cat>      
  </animals>
</xml>
```

Both `<bark>` and `<meow>` are in fact hiding the same concept, the "pitch" or "sound volume" of the animal, defined as a `String`.

I could do this:

#### Animal.java

```
public abstract class Animal {

    public abstract String getVolume();

}
```

All it would take would be implementing `getVolume()` in both `Cat.java` and `Dog.java` and return `this.bark` or `this.meow`, respectively.

However, it seems cleaner to have a `volume` attribute in `Animal.java` and somehow tell JAXB to map both of these fields to it.

**Am I overthinking this? How would you implement that?**

(Of course, I have no control over the input XML. I would also like to avoid solutions using MOXy if possible, as pushing for another dependency to this project might be difficult.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be to:

1. Mark the `Animal` class as `@XmlTransient` to remove it as a mapped class.
2. Override the `getVolume()` method in each of the subclasses annotating it to match the desired element for that class.

For this particular model though my preference would be for each animal to have a `volume` element.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB is actually have several polymorphic mechanisms. You can use 
`@XmlDescriminatorNode`/`@XmlDescrimintatorValue` (Eclipse MOXy) or substitution groups.

Here is some details and code examples: [substitution groups](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html), [descriminators](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html)